# Is it possible to dump (get a count) what is currently on the Event Dispatch Thread?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

Working with a rather involved application and there appears to be a delay with updating a Windows.

Adding debug and the timer shows a difference of up to 0.5 seconds between Timecheck 1 and Timecheck 2 which is actually very noticeable delay when drawing.

```
System.out.println("Timecheck 1 : " + new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss.SSS").format(new Date()));
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Timecheck 2 : " + new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss.SSS").format(new Date()));
        myFunctionCall(myData);
    }
});
```

The "myFunctionCall(myData);" call was removed from the invokeLater() and the delay is gone.

This tells me there is a lot going on within the EDT and the call was basically queued and took some time to get to.

Is that assumption correct?

If yes, then is there a way to check what is on the EDT right before making the call?

Seeing what calls are there may lead me to some excessive usage of the EDT or possibly see if the EDT is too busy may I make the call to `myFunctionCall(myData);` directly.

If overly busy, maybe I will call it directly and only use the EDT if there are minimal calls.

Comment: You can make the function call directly, but if the function hinges on anything maintained or updated by the EDT then you're looking at the possibility for data races and deadlocks. Depending on your application, a data race or deadlock may be far worse than a half second delay.

Comment: I assumed if not run right away the EDT is busy. If the EDT is not busy, why would it not run it immediately? I understand it is some unspecified time but to wait almost 0.5 seconds is almost an eternity in the computer world. ;-)

Comment: @JonnyHenly Events on the EDT *should* run very very quickly. A half second delay indicates somebody misusing it--likely doing expensive computations or blocking I/O calls, things that one is not supposed to do on the EDT.

Comment: Thanks John, is there anyway to dump the EDT to see what is there and possibly track down the misuse?

Comment: The following Stack Overflow question and its upvoted answer may shed some light. [How to monitor Event Dispatch Thread queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841987/how-to-monitor-event-dispatch-thread-queue)